# slide toggle from left to right in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using hide and show an element using the angular JS .  Angular toggle collapse working fine from slide up and slide down. How can I do the same thing sliding from right to left with some animation speed. 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse